# how to type to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

I am trying to have a multi line textbox that when you type in it streams it to the label, BUT the label has to have a max length of 15 so like once it reaches 15 characters in the textbox it should start overwriting the label since it reached it's max length

thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: What specific problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: What UI library are you using? WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: im using winforms and i dont know what to try because i dont know where to start :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of overwriting You want to achieve.

There are at least three methods you can use:

- **displaying always the last 15 characters from the textbox**, as described in the *Olivier's answer*
- **clearing the label's text each 15 characters inserted** and start filling in the label over again, you can use this code to achieve this:

  ```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      String text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "|");

      int startIndex = ((text.Length - 1) / 15) * 15;

      label1.Text = text.Substring(Math.Max(0, startIndex));
  }
  ```
- you can also **overwrite char by char when text length is over 15 characters**, however, I suppose it's **not** what you would like to achieve, because it would cause a mess in the textbox ;), however, it can be used as a kind of visual effect :). If you want code snippet for this, let me know :).
  **Update**
  Here's the code for the third overwriting method:

  ```
  String lastText = "";
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      String textBoxText = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "|");

      if (textBoxText.Length > lastText.Length)
      {
          int charIndex = (textBoxText.Length - 1) % 15;

          if (charIndex >= 0)
          {
              label1.Text = label1.Text.Insert(charIndex, textBoxText.Substring(textBoxText.Length - 1));
              if (charIndex < textBoxText.Length - 1)
              {
                  label1.Text = label1.Text.Remove(charIndex + 1, 1);
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          int charIndex = textBoxText.Length % 15;

          if (textBoxText.Length >= 15)
          {
              label1.Text = label1.Text.Insert(charIndex, textBoxText[textBoxText.Length - 15].ToString());
              if (charIndex < textBoxText.Length - 1)
              {
                  label1.Text = label1.Text.Remove(charIndex + 1, 1);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              label1.Text = label1.Text.Remove(label1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
          }
      }

      lastText = textBoxText;
  }
  ```

Comment: No problem :). I've added a code snippet for the third overwriting method mentioned. It's probably not the most optimized version, but it seems to work :).

Answer (score 2):

Add onchange event on text box :

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length<=15)  
{  
    label1.Caption=textBox1.Text;  
}
```

For example

Comment: yeah sorta but i want once the labels text reaches 15 to start overwriting itself with the other text in the textbox

Comment: It was a start, but you should check Tim S answer, he wrote better code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler to the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` that sets the `Label`'s content based on the text.  E.g. (untested, might have your concept wrong or be off by one somewhere)

```
int startIndex = Math.Max(0, myTextBox.Text.Length - 15);
int endIndex = Math.Min(myTextBox.Text.Length - 1, startIndex);
myLabel.Text = myTextBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Also, though it doesn't change your question/answer, you might want to look at using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`.  It allows things like line wrapping.  See some of the differences here: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/ (in WPF, should be similar whatever you're doing, though)

Comment: Excellent coding, but if I'm not mistaking Content is used in WPF.

Comment: it has to be a a label because when the label changes it has to get the text from the label and put it somewhere else

Comment: also when i do this, when i type into the textbox it makes the labels text "" idk if i did something wrong but thanks anyways :)

Comment: Hm, run debug to check what start and end/length numbers are coming up.  Seems like very straightforward code otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Floradu88, I'm only really familiar with Silverlight, where it's Content.  Ian, if this answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking the green check on the left.

Comment: it didnt sadly because when i do it. it just deleted the text in the label all together

Answer (score 1):

My solution always displays the last 15 characters in the label

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "|");
    int length = s.Length;
    if (length > 15) {
        label1.Text = s.Substring(length - 15);
    } else {
        label1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

I also replace the line-breaks with `|`. Since your textbox is in multiline mode, line-breaks are entered when you hit `<Enter>`.